Linearization that holds for any fixed parameter but not with limit
Consider this problem for $x\ll1$, and assume initially $a\neq 1$
$$
\frac{1}{1+(a-1)\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{x}{a-1} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{a-1}} = \frac{x}{a-1}\left (1 - \frac{x}{a-1} +\cdots\right)\approx \frac{x}{a-1}
$$
Now consider, $\lim_{a\to1}$,
$$
\lim_{a\to1} \frac{1}{1+(a-1)\frac{1}{x}} = 1
$$
but such limit cannot be done on the Taylor expansion.
Is the reason that it does not work that while for a fixed $a$, I can always find $x_0<1$ such that $\frac{x_0}{a}<1$ and the Taylor series converges close enough to $0$ but when I prescribe the limit, this no longer holds and the taylor series does not converge?
How would one go about such problems of linearization where one needs the linearization result to be valid in some limit such as shown above?

The limit cares about what happens for fixed $x$ as $a\to 1$. But your expansion does the opposite; you fix $a\neq 1$ and investigate what happens when $x\ll 1$.
I don’t see why you did this since there’s a perfectly good way of obtaining expansions valid in the regime you’re interested in. For any $a,x\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $\left|(a-1)\frac{1}{x}\right|<1$, we can expand as a geometric series:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+(a-1)\frac{1}{x}}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(a-1)^n}{x^n}.
\end{align}
Note that the set $\left\{(a,x)\in\Bbb{C}^2\,:\, |a-1|<|x|\right\}$ includes a lot of stuff. In particular, you can fix $x$ and let $a\to 1$. You can also fix any $\epsilon$ and consider ‘locally uniform’ expansions in the region where $|x|\geq \epsilon$ and $|a-1|<\epsilon$, i.e you can essentially consider ‘all’ values of $x$ and ‘all’ values of $a$ near $1$ simultaneously.
Etc.
But, if you want to consider what happens simultaneously as $x\to 0$ and $a\to 1$, then you can’t do this, because the answer really depends on the behaviour of the quotient $\frac{a-1}{x}$ (and this quotient does not have a limit as $(a,x)\to (1,0)$).

But $|(a-1)/x|<1$ is only valid in the limit $\lim_{a\to1}$, isn't it? Say, you fix $a=1.5$, but I want the expression to be valid for $x$ very around $0$ and the series only converges far away from the zero. In other words, $a$ is not limited to be close to $1$ at all. It actually can be say $1<a<2$, however, $x$ is close to $0$. To expand, I have an expression which reduces to a known expression for $a=1$. I want to linearize it and I would like the linearized form to also reduce to the known expression linearized.
